# How to generate postscript files from LaTeX pictures, with correct dimensions?

Tags: diagrams, postscript

I have a document containing, among other things, some figures created using the `picture` environment.  Now I need to create a postscript file for each figure, but if I simply copy them into otherwise blank documents, each one will take up an entire page.

For example, if I have

```
...
\setlength{\unitlength}{1in}
\begin{picture}(3.14,2.71)
  %Draw things
\end{picture}
...
```

then I would like to create a .PS file that is 3.14x2.71 inches and which contains nothing but this drawing.  I should be able to change my `picture` environment above to an `\includegraphics` command that loads the new file, and have it make zero change to the document that is output.

> What's the best way to create a postscript file from a LaTeX-drawn `picture` with the same dimensions as the original?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should look into the (extremely useful) [preview](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/preview) package. You'll probably want the `tightpage` option, and if you want the generated eps to have *exactly* the same dimensions as the original you'll need to `\setlength\PreviewBorder{0 pt}`.

You don't need to copy the `picture` environments into otherwise blank documents, you just need have a `\PreviewEnvironment{picture}` line in the preamble, in order to extract only the pictures.

To expand on your example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{0pt}
\PreviewEnvironment{picture}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\unitlength}{1in}
Text before picture
\begin{picture}(3.14,2.71)
 Contents of picture environment
\end{picture}
\begin{picture}(1.00,1.00)
 Contents of picture environment2
\end{picture}
Text after pictures
\end{document}
```

Gives, when compiled with pdflatex, a pdf which has pages of exactly 3.14in*2.71in and 1.00in*1.00in, and when compiled by latex and dvips gives a ps with the same dimension pages. Either the pdf or the ps can be turned into eps using external tools, but if you want to, you can replace `tightpage` with `psfixbb` and then run `dvips -E -i` on the dvi to get a series of eps files each with the correct dimensions (named jobname.001 jobname.002 etc, which you have to rename as jobname.001.eps etc).

Removing the `active` option from the `usepackage` line means the file will compile as if preview was never loaded.

PS: if you want the `\includegraphics` boxes to be very accurately the same as the original ones then you should also look into the `hiresbb` option of the `graphicx` package. Otherwise the dimensions get rounded to 1 `bp` (big point) accuracy.

Comment: This is a great solution, although it has shown me that not all of my pictures fit exactly within their prescribed areas.  This is most commonly due to placing a dot on the boundary, and results in the cutting off of half the dot, but I suppose that's more my fault than the package's...

Comment: Too late to edit my previous comment, but is it possible to create an eps file that has a defined bounding box, but also contains content outside of that?  Since that's essentially the case I have with the picture environments it would be the best way to accomplish what I'm after.

Comment: It is possible to have an eps file that extends beyond its bounding box, but I don't think that `preview` gives you any way to make one: the `tightpage` option actually changes the page size, not the bounding box; the `psfixbb` and `dvips -E -i` route causes the bounding box to be enlarged just enough that it catches the parts of your image that extend past the dimensions of the picture.

Answer (score 2):

Run `ps2eps` on the postscript file you produce. You'll get an encapsulated postscript that you can view with postscript viewers or embed via `\includegraphics`.

Comment: Thanks, that works fairly well, but the resulting bounding box is defined by the limits of the drawing, not the original dimensions of the picture.  If the drawing goes exactly to all four edges without going over then this will work perfectly, but for other scenarios the resulting eps file isn't quite the same size as the original picture so spacings near the image change...

Answer (score 1):

If you create the images as otherwise empty pdf pages (no page number!) you can then use
[pdfcrop](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/pdfcrop.html) to trim the whitespace