# Tight bounding box for EPS

Tags: eps, psfrag

This is a follow-up of the question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14402/eps-file-with-tight-bb-psfrag-labels.

I have this file named `model.eps` (see further below on how to get the file) and I am replacing the labels on the figure using `psfrag` commands. If I compile the file `test3.tex` using `latex` > `dvips` > `ps2pdf`, the resulting file is well-cropped and is the same as the size of the file `model.eps`. I am using the `standalone` package.

However I would like an EPS file instead of a PDF file. With `dvips` I can get a PS file. I tried the command:

```
dvips -D7200 -E test3.dvi -o test3.ps
```

making sure to use the `-E` switch in order to get a tight bounding box.

The resulting PS file (`test3.ps`) is not properly tight bounded on the left as you can see.

What am I doing wrong and how can I correct this fault?

All the files are in the folder `tightbounding` here at 
http://petitlien.fr/my_test_file.

Thank you for any suggestions...

**----
Update**

Running epstool:

`E:\new>epstool --bbox --copy test3.ps outfile.eps`

DSC Information

```
At line 9033:
                     <xapGImg:image>/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAgEASABIAAD/7QAsUGhvdG9zaG9w
IDMuMAA4QklNA+0AAAAAABAASAAAAAEA&#xA;AQBIAAAAAQAB/+4ADkFkb2JlAGTAAAAAAf/bAIQABgQ
EBAUEBgUFBgkGBQYJCwgGBggLDAoKCwoK&#xA;DBAMDAwMDAwQDA4PEA8ODBMTFBQTExwbGxscHx8fHx
8fHx8fHwEHBwcNDA0YE
```

Lines in DSC documents must be shorter than 255 characters.

```
"C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.01\bin\gswin32c.exe"  -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=bbox
 -c "<</PageSize [9400 9400] /PageOffset [3000 3000]>> setpagedevice" -f "c:\doc
ume~1\yogcal\locals~1\temp\gsviewa01924"
GPL Ghostscript 9.01 (2011-02-07)
Copyright (C) 2010 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software comes with NO WARRANTY: see the file PUBLIC for details.
%%BoundingBox: 0 0 0 0
%%HiResBoundingBox: 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
OK
```

**I'm getting the bounding box as 0 0 0 0. Why?**

Comment: Check [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2059/how-to-generate-postscript-files-from-latex-pictures-with-correct-dimensions)

Answer (score 3):

install the program `epstool`, available for Windows and Linux and then run

```
epstool --bbox --copy infile.eps outfile.eps
```

then `outfile.eps` should have a correct bounding box.

Comment: Thanks. I am having problems to run epstool on Windows but I shall play with it and make it work. Epstool is putting the bounding box as 0 0 0 0 and it terminates normally. It can locate my Ghostscript. There must be something else which I need to do.

Comment: I've posted the output I get using epstool above in my post. 1 vote up in the meantime.

Answer (score 1):

The dvips manual states that it will not look at included graphics when calculating the bounding box. Perhaps you could add a white framed box around the figure?