# picture width problem

Tags: diagrams

I need to make the picture with the width of one column in two column paper, and I wrote `\linewidth` but it doesn't work as shown below; it's smaller than the width and also it is very small. I need to make it bigger; any help?

[image: my photo]

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Data/classoutput.eps}\label{pic10}
\caption{Caption}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: You most like have a white border around the image. To see whether this is the case, use `\fbox{\includegraphics[width=\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule]{<image>}}`.

Comment: no i didn't want to have a border, i need to increase the width of the photo from both side

Comment: What I'm saying is that `\fbox` will show you whether you actually already have a white border around the image. Post the output with what I presented above so we can see what it looks like.

Comment: it made a big black border but the pic size is the same

Comment: The picture is supposed to stay the same size (actually a tad smaller). Either way, it idea behind asking you to actually show the image with the border would be to highlight whether or not there is a thick **white** border around your image. If so (which is likely), then you should use [`epstool`](http://ctan.org/pkg/epstool) to trim the whitespace around the image...

Comment: See [Tight bounding box for EPS](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14481/5764).

Comment: May be the source figure fontsize is too small. I guess it's  from matlab use [matlab figures with latex fonts](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/78477/15717). Always export to exact figure size(width and height) with bigger fontsize and legend as per two columns width available. Off-topic: 1. No need for figure extension(classoutput) 2. change \label{pic10} to \label{fig:picture-details} to separate other tags 3.always \label after the \caption or inside \caption{caption \label}

Answer (score 3):

your image has a lot of whitespace around it. You can clip the image with

```
\includegraphics[trim=20 20 20 20,clip]{...}
```

(choose correct four values, in my example it is 20pt on all sides).

Comment: Technically, `trim` is done using `bp`s. See p 10 of the [`graphics` guide](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/graphics/grfguide.pdf). Of course, [the difference is marginal](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8260/5764).

Answer (score 0):

With PSTricks.

[image]

```
% filename is main.tex
% compile it with pdflatex -shell-escape main.tex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{dummy.tex}
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newsavebox\IBox
\sbox\IBox{\includegraphics{example-image-a}}

\psset
{
    xunit=\dimexpr\wd\IBox/10,
    yunit=\dimexpr\ht\IBox/10,
}

\addtopsstyle{gridstyle}
{
    griddots=0,
    gridcolor=red,
    gridwidth=0.4pt,
    subgriddiv=5,
    subgridcolor=green!50,
    subgridwidth=0.1pt,
    gridlabels=5pt,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=top](10,10)
    \rput[bl](0,0){\usebox\IBox}
\end{pspicture}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](5,5)(10,10)
\psclip{\psframe[dimen=middle,linestyle=none](5,5)(10,10)}
    \rput[bl](0,0){\usebox\IBox}
\endpsclip
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}

\immediate\write18{latex dummy}
\immediate\write18{dvips dummy}
\immediate\write18{ps2pdf dummy.ps}


\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
Karl's students do not care about dashing patterns.
\begin{figure}[hbtp]
\centering
\includegraphics[page=2,width=0.8\linewidth]{dummy}
\caption{The cropped image}
\label{fig:TheCroppedImage}
\end{figure}
Karl's students do not care about arrow tips. Karl's students, by the way, do not know what a transformation matrix is.
\end{document}
```