# Error getting bounding box of .eps figure

Tags: eps, epstool

After reading the question ["Tight bounding box for EPS"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14481/tight-bounding-box-for-eps) and applying the @Herbert answer, when I run:

> epstool.exe --bbox --copy infile.eps outfile.eps

I get this error:

> "gswin32c.exe"  -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=bbox   -c "<> setpagedevice" -f "c:\users\bguerr~1.3\appdata\local\temp\gsviewa14320"
>
> **Ghostscript failed to obtain bounding box**
>
> Failed

However, I checked the eps file with a text editor and apparently the bounding box information is properly defined

> %%BoundingBox: 114 407 585 680.

So, anyone knows what is wrong with my epstool command?

Update

@IanThompson here is the used file [infile.eps](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_9VwvAvMQwHZUVDMVJtS0ZGeGs/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Perhaps process `infile.eps` using `eps2eps infile.eps infile2.eps` and then try with `epstool infile2.eps ...`. Perhaps there is some corruption of `infile.eps`.

Comment: Can you make the eps file available for download and add a link here?

Comment: Are there by any change binary junk in the file? Sometimes there is binary junk before %! PS a few that can throw of some programs

Comment: I update my answer by including the file

Comment: on Linux the `epstool` command works with the provided file, and indeed the bounding box is cropped - however for some reason a page number is added.

Comment: @Marijn, I try it in Windows with Miktex and Texmaker and I guest that the page number appears for a fancyheader or similar package used when I compile the .tex to generate the eps file (via latex -> dvi2eps ). Probably if I use \pagestyle{empty} the page number disappears. In my home I'll try with Linux, but I should work both Windows and Linux